# Cannot find corresponding Doctrine objects

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm using SF5 with the latest FosElastica bundle.

I have 2 entities with a OneToMany relation.

entity User 1 -> x Groups

my fos_elastica.yaml looks like:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        test:
            use_alias: true
            types:
                users:
                    properties:
                        id: ~
                        email: ~
                        groups:
                            type: "nested"
                            include_in_parent: true
                            properties:
                                id: ~
                                name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: App\Entity\User
```

When I populate the data I have:

```
{
"_index": "test_2020-03-23-081137",
"_type": "users",
"_id": "EtxyBnEBaS6kXWokfVYU",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"id": null,
"email": "somedata",
groups": [{
  'id': 1
  'name': 'Group name'
}]
}
```

When I make a Search I have the error

> Cannot find corresponding Doctrine objects (0) for all Elastica results (4). Missing IDs: EtxyBnEBaS6kXWokfVYU

How should I configure my types with a OneToMany relation ?